# Updating single row when using IN in update statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query

```
$id='1,2,3,4';
$db->query("UPDATE users SET active=0 WHERE id IN('$id')");
```

It is updating only the last id ie. 4
Is something wrong with my SQL statement?

Comment: Jd's answer is of course correct - but FIND_IN_SET *is* blisteringly fast

Comment: @Strawberry didnt know about FIND_IN_SET tnx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the quotes

```
where id IN($id)
```

The `IN` clause needs seperate entries and not a single string with comma seperated values in it. Example:

```
where id IN(1,2)      -> correct
where id IN('1','2')  -> correct
where id IN('1,2')    -> wrong
```